# Is this arrogance or something else?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do I call someone who has a "things are as I say they are" attitude?

Example: I say the sky is green, if you don't agree I will punch you till you do.

or

Example: Someone says they are from a city when fact is they are from somewhere else. When you confront them with the truth they react like you haven't said anything.

Comment: How big are they?

Comment: lol. average height, slightly plump and old.

Comment: In that case he's a "stubborn bastard".

Answer (score 3):

The act of being [***intransigent***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intransigent) or [***adamant***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adamant), as described in your question, is distinct from the act of being ***untruthful*** or ***false***, as shown in your example. I can think of no single word that expresses both, simultaneously.